# Select Dropdown Value in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I would like to select an option provided from the dropdown.

```py
class GuestForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Full Name', [validators.length(min=1, max=50)])
    phone = StringField('Phone')
    adults = StringField('Adults')
    status = SelectField('Status', choices=[('BK', 'Booked'), ('CK', 'Cancelled')])
```

**Route**

```py
@app.route('/edit_guest/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_guest(id):
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    # Get guest by id
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE id = %s", [id])
    guest = cur.fetchone()
    # Get form
    form = GuestForm(request.form)

    # Populate Guest form fields
    form.name.data = guest['name']
    form.phone.data = guest['phone']
    form.adults.data = guest['adults']
    form.status.data = guest['status']

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        name = request.form['name']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        adults = request.form['adults']
        status = request.form['status']
```

**Jinja2 template**

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>{{render_field(form.name, class_="form-control")}}</td>
            <td>{{render_field(form.phone, class_="form-control")}}</td>
            <td>{{render_field(form.adults, class_="form-control")}}</td>
            <td>{{render_field(form.status, class_="form-control")}}</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I submit after selecting the value it says "Not a valid choice" below dropdown value.

Comment: Hi @Jeevan, please add some context on what works and what does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand. For someone how has not seen your code, it is hard to combine code snippets. There are many good tutorials out there to get a good understanding in Flask Forms. I think you should invest some time there to get a better understanding.

Nevertheless, I tried to provide you a minimal running example. The example creates a form which you can submit. For your next questions, please try to come up with a minimal example yourself.

**dropdown.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template_string, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.fields import *
from wtforms.validators import *


class GuestForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Full Name', [Length(min=1, max=50)])
    phone = StringField('Phone')
    adults = StringField('Adults')
    status = SelectField('Status', choices=[('BK', 'Booked'), ('CK', 'Cancelled')])


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False

@app.route('/edit_guest/<string:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_guest(id):

    # Instead of hard coding, read data from database based on id
    # result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM guests WHERE id = %s", [id])
    # guests ...
    guests = {'name': 'John', 'phone': '123456', 'adults': 2, 'status': 'BK'}

    form = GuestForm(data=guests)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Update data in database
        # "UPDATE guests SET ... WHERE id = id
        # access new data with **form.data
        guests = form.data

        return redirect(url_for("edit_guest", id="Test-id"))

    return render_template_string(
    """
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tbody>
                        {% for field in form %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ field.label() }} </td>
                                <td>{{ field() }} </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type='submit'></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    """, form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: No worries, the above answer does not solve the issue. Thanks for your time.